# Highcharts MapBubble - Is it possible to load the data by using the data module?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to create a Map Bubble which will receive live data from a csv or json or any kind of external file. I understand that the way to do that is to use the data module and set data.enablePolling to true.

My static chart is the following:

```
        Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            map: 'custom/world'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Map'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Activity in the last 60 minutes'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: false,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Countries',
            color: '#717171',
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            name: 'Visitors',
            color: '#ff4013',
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code2'],
            data: [{ "code2": "CA", "desc": "Canada", "z": 2 }],
            minSize: 20,
            maxSize: '20%',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.desc}: {point.z} visitors'
            }
        }],

    });
```

Is it possible to import the data by setting data.csvURL, data.rowsURL or data.columnsURL instead of using the series.data ? I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

here is an sample on how to use data module with Highcharts Maps.
The trick is to use parsed to map external data to series data.

```js
Highcharts.data({
  table: 'datatable',

  parsed: function(columns) {
    let data = []

    for(let i = 1; i < columns[0].length; i++){
      let dataPoint = {code2: undefined, desc: undefined, z: undefined}
      dataPoint.code2 = columns[0][i]
      dataPoint.desc = columns[1][i]
      dataPoint.z = columns[2][i]
      data.push(dataPoint)
    }

    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
      chart: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          map: 'custom/world'
      },
    
      title: {
          text: 'Map'
      },
    
      subtitle: {
          text: 'Activity in the last 60 minutes'
      },
    
      legend: {
          enabled: false
      },
    
      mapNavigation: {
          enabled: false,
          buttonOptions: {
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
      },
    
      series: [{
          name: 'Countries',
          color: '#717171',
          enableMouseTracking: true
      }, {
          type: 'mapbubble',
          name: 'Visitors',
          color: '#ff4013',
          joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code2'],
          data: data,
          minSize: 20,
          maxSize: '20%',
          tooltip: {
              pointFormat: '{point.desc}: {point.z} visitors'
          }
      }],
    
    });
  }

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>

<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>code2</th>
            <th>desc</th>
            <th>z</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>CA</th>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DE</th>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution I was looking for to implement a Bubble Map which is updated in real time. I am using .net with UpdatePanels and the data for the map are coming from an SQL Server.

HTML

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>    
        <asp:HiddenField ID="ChartTitle"
            runat="server" />

        <asp:HiddenField ID="ChartData"
            runat="server" />

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Code Behind to Bind the Data

```
    Private Sub BindData()

    Dim enMapData As New MapData
    Dim strStoredProcedure As String
    strStoredProcedure = "LastXMinVisitors"

    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DbConnection").ConnectionString()
    Dim mySqlDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataset As New DataSet()
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection.Open()
        Using myCommand As New SqlCommand(strStoredProcedure, myConnection)
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            myCommand.CommandTimeout = 300
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastx", -60)
            mySqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset)
            myConnection.Close()

            Dim n As Integer = 0
            enMapData.UniqueVisitors = 0
            For Each row As DataRow In myDataset.Tables(0).Rows
                n += 1
                enMapData.UniqueVisitors += row.Item("Visitors")
                enMapData.DataPoints &= "{" & Chr(34) & "code2" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & row.Item("Country") & Chr(34)
                enMapData.DataPoints &= ", " & Chr(34) & "desc" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & row.Item("CountryName") & Chr(34)
                enMapData.DataPoints &= ", " & Chr(34) & "cont" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & row.Item("Continent") & Chr(34)
                enMapData.DataPoints &= ", " & Chr(34) & "z" & Chr(34) & ": " & row.Item("Visitors").ToString & "}"
                If n < myDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count Then
                    enMapData.DataPoints &= ", "
                End If
            Next row

            enMapData.Title = enMapData.UniqueVisitors.ToString & " Visitors"

        End Using
    End Using

    ' Load Chart Data to HiddenField ASP controls
    ChartTitle.Value = enMapData.Title
    ChartData.Value = enMapData.DataPoints

    Return

End Sub
```

Timer in Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    BindData()
End Sub
```

JS launched after asynchronous calls - Pageloaded function fires each time an asynchronous callback launched on behalf of an UpdatePanel control completes and the content inside that UpdatePanel is updated.

```
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

    function pageLoaded(sender, args) {

        var chartTitle = document.getElementById("<%=ChartTitle.ClientID%>").value;
        var chartData = '[' + document.getElementById("<%=ChartData.ClientID%>").value + ']';
        var cpoints = JSON.parse(chartData);

        chart.setTitle({ text: chartTitle });
        chart.series[1].setData(cpoints, true, true);

    }
```

And finally the Map

```
        var chart = new Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            map: 'custom/world',
        },

        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: false,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                name: 'Countries',
                color: '#717171',
                enableMouseTracking: true
            },
            {
                type: 'mapbubble',
                name: 'Visitors',
                color: '#ff4013',
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code2'],
                data: cpoints,
                minSize: 12,
                maxSize: 50,
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    headerFormat: '<b>LAST 60 min</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.desc} <br/> {point.cont} <br/> {point.z} visitors'
                }
            }],

    });
```

The trick for me was the **chart.setTitle** and the **chart.series[1].setData** which is forcing a redraw of the map when points are changed!